# How do you find a specific tag based on parents in capybara and rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Currently I have two tests that each individually test for a button_click within a form on the same page with no `id`s but both have the same text `Go`.  So what is happens is capybara/rspec only tests the first instance of the `Go` button for **both** tests.   Is there a way to find something based on the parents? I don't want to have to modify my functional code by adding an id just for the sole purpose of testing.  I was thinking of something like `test_form > input[type='submit']` but that doesn't work.

Current code:

```
let(:submit) {"Go"}

describe "with valid information" do
  before do
    fill_in "email",        with: "stuff@example.com"
    fill_in "password",     with: "stuff"
  end

  it "should create a user" do
    expect {click_button submit}.to change(User, :count).by(1)
  end
end
```

Current Gems:

```
rails 3.2.6
rspec-rails 2.10.1
capybara 1.1.2
```

Comment: you can specify `within` which selector you want your button

Comment: I just tried to enclose the above describe block with a  `within('#signup_form') do` and I'm getting a `undefined method `within'` error.  Do I need to install anything extra for this?

Comment: you should not have to see doc: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/

Comment: Can you put this as an answer?  This solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify within which selector you want your button, [see doc](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/)